# Is testing html validation possible with jest and rtl?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, testing, web

so i basically test if after the submit is clicked the fetch request is sent by checking if its called. The Issue is that it's being sent wether the requirements are met or not. (it works in the browser if i test manually). So at the end its being called multiple times when its only supposed to be called one time.

```
  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(screen.getByLabelText("Title:")).toHaveValue("Channel 1"); // wait until form is rendered
  });

  const titleInput = screen.getByTestId('titleInput');
  const saveButton = screen.getByText('Save');
  expect(titleInput).toHaveAttribute('required');

  // try submit with a title that is too short
  fireEvent.change(titleInput, { target: { value: '' } });
  await userEvent.click(saveButton);
  expect(editChannel).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
  

  // try submit with a title that is too long 
  fireEvent.change(titleInput, { target: { value: longText } });
  await userEvent.click(saveButton);
  expect(editChannel).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);

  // correctly fill Title
  fireEvent.change(titleInput, { target: { value: 'New Title' } });
  await userEvent.click(saveButton);

  expect(screen.getByText("Title:")).toBeInTheDocument()
  expect(editChannel).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

this is part of my component

```
        <React.Fragment>
           
            <Badge>Edit Channel Properties</Badge>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <p><label>Title:&nbsp;
                    <input type="text" id="title" onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)} defaultValue={oldChannel?.name} 
                        minLength={5} maxLength={50}  required data-testid="titleInput"  />
                </label></p>
                <p><label>Description:&nbsp;
                    <input type="textarea" id="description" onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)} defaultValue={oldChannel?.description}
                        minLength={5} maxLength={50} /* required */ />
                </label></p>
                <label>Visibility:&nbsp;
                <select id="visibility" onChange={(e) => setVisible(e.target.value === "true")}  defaultValue={oldChannel?.public.toString()} >
                    <option value="true" >Public</option>
                    <option value="false">Private</option>
                </select>
                </label>
                <p></p>
                <label>Status:&nbsp; 
                <select id="Closed" onChange={(e) => setClosed(e.target.value === "true")} defaultValue={oldChannel?.closed.toString()} >  
                    <option value="false" >Open</option>
                    <option value="true">Closed</option>
                </select>
                </label>
                <p><label>Change Owner with ID:&nbsp;
                    <input type="textarea"
                        minLength={5} maxLength={50}/>
                </label></p>
                <button type="submit">Save</button>
            </form>

            <Button onClick={() => navigate(-1)}> Cancel </Button>
        </React.Fragment>
```

editChannel is called on submit and i mocked it like this in the test:

```
  (editChannel as jest.Mock).mockImplementation(() => jest.fn(() => console.log("editChannel called")));
```

Comment: i guess its not possible